# Non-static method mysqli::init() cannot be called statically

Tags: php, mysqli

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.init.php

```
$ConnectionResource = mysqli::init();
```

The above code fails with:

Fatal error: Non-static method mysqli::init() cannot be called statically

How come?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

that's just stupid notation used in the manual, obviously they use `class->property` and `class::method` without regard for the actual language and its distinction between instance- and class-member access (`->` vs. `::`).  see example 1 at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php

Comment: I dun get it. So the correct syntax is $mysqli->init() ??? But isn't the whole point of init to create that $mysqli var in the first place?